# How to Compute Hamming Distance of two VARCHAR's in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hamming-distance

In my table, I have two columns of the Datatype 'Varchar' with the same length. These columns are binary representations of information, and I would like to select the Hamming Distance between them, but I can't find any function to do that. Does anyone have any guidance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hamming Distance / Similarity searches in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606492/hamming-distance-similarity-searches-in-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

Create an auxiliary numbers table with unique sequential integers at least up until the max string length and then you can do

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(@String1) = LEN(@String2) THEN COUNT(*) END
FROM   dbo.Numbers
WHERE  Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@String1)
       AND SUBSTRING(@String1, Number, 1) <> SUBSTRING(@String2, Number, 1)
```

In future product versions the auxiliary numbers table can be swapped out by the `GENERATE_SERIES` function.

NB: If you are planning on running this calculation over many strings - e.g. to return the row with the closest Hamming Distance you'll likely find performance an issue though...

Comment: Perhaps add   ...  AND LEN(@String1) = LEN(@String2)   Either way +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - the "with the same length" was a given in the question here. I'll add that anyway though to be on the safe side (and replace the `COUNT` with `SUM(1)` so `NULL` is returned for that case rather than zero